# What to do about noisy drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain

I live in 7 store city building in Prague.

Last night I couldn't sleep not only because of the hot weather, but also thanks to drain which just wouldn't shut up. It makes gurgly noises every now and then. I never noticed it during the day, but then during the day I'm at work.

I assume this is caused by water falling from other apartments down the drain, causing decrease of the pressure in the drain pipe, which is balanced through the drain in my kitchen. I tried to temporarily solve the problem by clogging the drain with some rags but it wasn't enough.

Is the cause I assumed correct? Either way, what can I do to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an air admittance valve might help.

[image]
*<sup>From [rmit.edu.au](https://www.dlsweb.rmit.edu.au/toolbox/plumbing/toolbox12_01/units/cpcpdr4001a_sanitary/00_groundwork/page_005.htm)</sup>*

[image]

Depending on space restrictions, you could instead consider replacing a normal P-trap or bottle-trap with an "anti-siphon trap"

[image]
<sup>Example - McAlpine "Silentrap"</sup>

> The major advantage of the Silentrap over Resealing Traps is that because the air is drawn through the Valve and not through the water seal, **gurgling is eliminated** and a much quieter discharge is ensured

...

> Whenever syphonic conditions develop, the negative pressure causes the Valve to rise, allowing air to be drawn into the discharge pipe. The pressure is thereby neutralised before it can have any effect on the water seal within the Trap. On cessation of the syphonic action, the Valve closes, making the Silentrap air and **watertight**

...

> The Silentrap has been most rigorously tested and will not unseal, even under the most abnormal conditions

My emphasis.

There is an unusually good [explanatory video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUha2Xp9HGs) which demonstrates the operation of this and other types of air-admittance valve (AAV)

This is just an example, Other brands are available and probably work just as well.

Comment: Is that guaranteed to never leak water out? Looks like having a hole in the pipe...

Comment: @TomášZato: I don't have one but I *believe* they contain a water-tight valve, air can get in - but water cannot get out. If was just a hole it would almost certainly be described as a vent (and be a potential source of unpleasant smells, so no-one would buy one and they would quickly no longer be made) ... updating answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a drain plug that will give you a watertight seal. If you can plug the sink so it holds water then the vent stack can't draw air through your sink.

This will then stop your sink from gurgling.

Good luck!

Comment: The sink has also overflow pipe *and* pipe that goes to dish draining area. Those pipes must remain functional.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a bathroom sink there is usually an overflow that also connects to the drain. Some tape over the vent and a little water left in the sink may be all you need.

Comment: Well, that's a nice hack, but that overflow is there for a reason.